# Odd CakePHP error

Tags: php, cakephp, cryptography, version

```
Warning (2): Parameter 1 to Employment::beforeFind() expected to be a reference, value given [CORE/Cake/Event/CakeEventManager.php, line 244]
```

I've been trying to add the Cryptable behavior to models in another person's application. The application completely worked beforehand. Here's what I added:

app/Model/Behavior/CryptableBehavior.php

```
    function setup(&$model, $settings) {
        if (!isset($this->settings[$model->alias])) { 
            $this->settings[$model->alias] = array( 
                'fields' => array(),
               'all' => true 
            ); 
        } 

        $this->settings[$model->alias] = array_merge($this->settings[$model->alias], $settings); 
    } 

    function beforeFind(&$model, $queryData) { 
        foreach ($this->settings[$model->alias]['fields'] AS $field) { 
            if (isset($queryData['conditions'][$model->alias.'.'.$field]) || $this->settings[$model->alias]['all']) { 
                $queryData['conditions'][$model->alias.'.'.$field] = $this->encrypt($queryData['conditions'][$model->alias.'.'.$field]); 
            } 
        } 
        return $queryData; 
    } 

    function afterFind(&$model, $results, $primary) { 
      foreach ($this->settings[$model->alias]['fields'] AS $field) { 
            if ($primary) { 
                foreach ($results AS $key => $value) { 
                    if (isset($value[$model->alias][$field]) || $this->settings[$model->alias]['all']) { 
                        $results[$key][$model->alias][$field] = $this->decrypt($value[$model->alias][$field]); 
                    } 
                } 
            } else { 
                if (isset($results[$field])) { 
                    $results[$field] = $this->decrypt($results[$field]); 
                } 
            } 
        } 

        return $results; 
    } 

    function beforeSave(&$model) { 
        foreach ($this->settings[$model->alias]['fields'] AS $field) { 
            if (isset($model->data[$model->alias][$field]) || $this->settings[$model->alias]['all']) { 
                $model->data[$model->alias]['cleartext_'.$field] = $model->data[$model->alias][$field]; 
                $model->data[$model->alias][$field] = $this->encrypt($model->data[$model->alias][$field]); 
            } 
        } 
        return true; 
    } 

    public function encrypt($data) { 
        if ($data !== '') { 
            return base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(Configure::read('Cryptable.cipher'), Configure::read('Cryptable.key'), $data, 'cbc', Configure::read('Cryptable.iv')));
        } else { 
            return ''; 
        } 
    } 

    public function decrypt($data, $data2 = null) { 
        if (is_object($data)) { 
            unset($data); 
            $data = $data2; 
        } 

        if ($data != '') { 
            return trim(mcrypt_decrypt(Configure::read('Cryptable.cipher'), Configure::read('Cryptable.key'), base64_decode($data), 'cbc', Configure::read('Cryptable.iv')));
        } else { 
            return ''; 
        } 
    } 
}
```

app/Model/Employment.php

```
<?php
class Employment extends AppModel {
    var $actsAs = array(
    'Cryptable' => array("all" => true)
   ); #this is the only line I added here
  public $name = 'Employment';
}
```

app/Config/bootstrap.php

```
[...]
Configure::write('Cryptable.cipher', 'rijndael-192');
Configure::write('Cryptable.key','******************');
Configure::write('Cryptable.iv', base64_decode('**************************')); #not the exact lenggth
[...]
```

php -v

```
PHP 4.4.9 (cgi-fcgi) (built: Jul 22 2013 09:48:43)
Copyright (c) 1997-2008 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v1.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2004 Zend Technologies
```

app/../lib/Cake/VERSION.txt

```
[...]
2.1.2
```

I repeat, despite the apparent version mismatch, everything used to work before. Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the model behaviors are called via [`call_user_func_array`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) which can only pass by value, not by reference. But [objects in PHP are always passed by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php). So you can just remove the ampersands (`&`) from in front of `$model` your function definitions. Your function definitions should look something like this:

```
function setup($model, $settings) { ... } 

function beforeFind($model, $queryData) { ... } 

function afterFind($model, $results, $primary) { ... } 

function beforeSave($model) { ... }
```